# Remove controls for mutliple HTML5 videos

Tags: javascript, html, video, custom-controls

I am creating a page with videos in a grid layout. It is going to be a huge project, so I need to access the video holder from classes. I have created new controls, but I am unable to hide the original html5 controls. 
This works:

```
var player = document.getElementById('vid1');
player.removeAttribute('controls');
```

This does not (have also tried to apply a class and access that, but no luck):

```
var player = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
player.removeAttribute('controls');
```

How can I easily access all the video holders and hide the controls?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do querySelectorAll, getElementsByClassName and other getElementsBy\* methods return?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-getelementsbyclassname-and-other-getelementsby-method)

Comment: If you really don't want controls in video element. Then remove it from its tag itself in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName` returns an array-like object of the elements with the specified tag name in the page.

This array-like object does not have a `removeAttribute` method, it is just a container used to hold the elements returned by your `document.getElementsByTagName` call; The DOM objects in that array-like have `removeAttribute` methods.

You will have to iterate through the array-like and remove the attributes from each of them individually:

```js
    var players = document.getElementsByTagName('video');
    
    for(var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
    players[i].removeAttribute('controls');
    }

    // the "video" HTML elements now have no "controls" attribute.
    console.log(players);
```

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls></video>
<video width="320" height="240" controls></video>
<video width="320" height="240" controls></video>
```

If you want to do it all in 1 statement (I prefer this one, we are borrowing `Array#map`):

```js
Array.prototype.map.call(document.getElementsByTagName("video"), function(el){
el.removeAttribute("controls");
});
```

```html
<video width="320" height="240" controls></video>
<video width="320" height="240" controls></video>
<video width="320" height="240" controls></video>
```